# jquery: how to prevent jquery from glitching if a toggle() or fadeIn() animation is called from a button?

Tags: jquery, html

I made a menu with buttons that load pages in the page with an fadeIn() antimation. if I change FadeIn() for toggle("slide") it does also not work properly.

when I spam the button the page will only load half or glitches(the loaded page is 0.5 transparant), how can I prevent spamming or glitching from happening?

**code** 
**jquery**

```
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#nav a').click(function(e) { 
          $('#content').hide().load( $(this).attr('href') , function(){
                 $('#content').fadeIn();
          });
          return false
    })
})

</script>
```

**Html code menu**

```
    <div id="nav"class="menu">
<ul >
  <li ><a  href="test0" >Home</a></li>
  <li ><a  href="test1.php">times</a></li>
  <li ><a  href="test2.php">Contact</a></li>
  <li ><a  href="producten.php">Products</a></li>
  <li ><a  href="test3">About</a></li>
</ul>

    </div>
```

**Html div #content**

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

tnx for reading hope someone can help me if you dont understand my question plz edit or ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a .stop() in front of your fadeIn().

so:

```
$(function(){
    $('#nav a').click(function(e) { 
          $('#content').hide().load( $(this).attr('href') , function(){
                 $('#content').stop().fadeIn();
          });
          return false
    })
})
```

Comment: yes, but you can also try .stop(true, true); 

https://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
  $('#nav a').click(function(e) { 
     $('#content').hide().load( $(this).attr('href') , function(){
      $('#content').stop( true, true ).fadeIn();
     });
     return false
  })
 })
 
 </script>                                                                                        this does not work

Comment: you have to have something else going on. Its loading your data and fading right, its just when you click a lot the animation gets confused? Here's the code I am using and it is fading in and out just fine. jQuery(function(){
  jQuery('#nav a').click(function(e) {
    jQuery('#content').hide(function(){
      jQuery('#content').stop().fadeIn();

  });
   return false
}) ;
});

Now, I did take out the load functionality, since I assumed that was working just fine and didn't need it.